# Array Modifier - Fit Curve too short

Tags: bezier-curves, modifiers

I want to create a simple road. To do this I first want to apply an 'Array Modifier' which fits the curve. So in the Array modifier I changed the 'Fit Type' from 'Fixed Count' to 'Fit Curve'. But now the Path is much shorter than the road it self.

And If I extrude the curve the road goes even longer and longer.
Is there a way the road is as long as the path?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the problem is that the objects have a different scale. Select both the curve and the path and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and apply the scale. As the *Apply Scale* will change the curve vertices radius, bring them back to 1 in the 3D View *N* panel.

Comment: Cool, Ctrl+A did it!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a plane with default values a bezier-curve with default values with these modifier settings on the plane object:

[image]